# SQL-Alchemy join query - most efficient way to query

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to generate a query and having difficulty finding the most efficient way to do it in sqlalchemy, (note I'm using flask-sqlalchemy)

The goal is to find all users have a meeting with a specific user.

So let's say Frank has 10 meetings coming up, I want to generate a list of all people frank has a meeting with.

Here are my models:

```
class UserMeeting(db.Model):
    """ Associative table, links meetings to users in a many to many fashion"""
    __tablename__ = 'userMeeting'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    meeting_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('meeting.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)

class Meeting(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "meeting"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(128))
    #... other columns
    #associative reference
    attendees = db.relationship('UserMeeting', backref='meeting')

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    #associative reference
    attendingMeetings = db.relationship("UserMeeting", backref="user", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
#Assume frank's a user with id == 1
frank = User.query.get(1)
franks_meetings = Meeting.query.join(Meeting.attendees).filter(UserMeeting.user == frank).all()
#not efficient way of getting users in meetings with frank
users = []
for meeting in franks_meetings:
    for userMeeting in meeting.attendees:
        if userMeeting.user != frank:
            users.append(userMeeting.user)

#is there a way to just generate one query and get this data?
```

I seem to be missing how I could just use joins to get this data. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a list of people? Distinct people? Your current code will have dupes if Frank is meeting the same person more than once, even though you are not keeping track of which meeting each one is in.

Comment: Great point, I overlooked that in my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the UserMeeting table with itself, using meeting_id as the join key. You may need to alias the table in order to reference it twice. I don't know if I can type the sqlalchemy syntax for it off the top of my head, but the sql looks like:

```
select distinct(b.user_id) as other_user_id
from usermeeting a
inner join usermeeting b
on a.meeting_id=b.meeting_id
where a.user_id=1 and b.user_id != 1;
```

And `1` is Frank.

Oh, and getting the user details too. Probably you could end up with `User` objects directly from doing this in sqlalchemy:

```
select distinct(u.id), u.email
from usermeeting a
inner join usermeeting b
on a.meeting_id=b.meeting_id
inner join users u
on b.user_id=u.id
where a.user_id=1 and b.user_id != 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the SQL! The join with the UserMeeting to itself was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the sqlalchemy version of the query for reference:

```
#get all users in meetings with Frank, (frank.id == 1)
um = aliased(UserMeeting)
frank = User.query.get(1)

q = session.query(User).join(User.attendingMeetings).\
    filter(UserMeeting.meeting_id == um.meeting_id).\
    filter(UserMeeting.user_id != frank.id, um.user_id == frank.id)

users_meeting_with_frank = q.all()
```